# CDF to normalize data

Tags: methods, normalization, cdf, standardized

I really need your help. I want to scale my data between 0 and 1 to cluster it afterwards. Does it make sense to use the cummalitive distribution function (CDF) to normalize the data in advance? (My features have different value ranges.) Please with reason. Is there anything comparable in the literature? I didn't really find anything. I am very grateful for help!